# in clojure - How to use a list elements one by one?

Tags: list, clojure, struct

i'm using a StructMap in Clojure, and trying to add map using struct by a list of values.
currently my struct includes only 3 keys, so i'm using the following to add new struct:

```
(struct user-struct (first list-vals) (second list-vals) (nth list-vals 2))
```

but now i want to use a dynamic struct which the user will choose how many keys will be in.
so in need to use some sort of loop which returns the list's element one by one.

does anybody has an idea how should i do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
(apply struct user-struct list-vals)
```

NOTE: List elements count should be same as the struct fields count

Comment: You don't need `partial`. `(apply struct user-struct list-vals)` works just as well.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://clojure.org/data_structure, most uses of StructMaps would now be better served by records.

You should try to switch from structmap to record.